# Is 'datus' used for a date in Latin?

Tags: etymology, time, calendarium

In many languages the word for date (a specific day, such as January 2, 2019) seems to come from the Latin participle *datus*: we have the English "date", the Italian "data", the Swedish "datum", and others.
Do these words come from a Latin phrase such as *dies datus/data*?
If yes, **when** is it attested?
Latin origin seems evident, but I wonder whether it is classical or a later development.

Comment: FWIW, the dates of letters in Latin (at least contemporarily) use the participle: _datae Romae, dies N..._ (or _datus_ if it is a decree, for example)

Comment: @Rafael Interesting! So the participle refers to the letter/decree/document, not the date itself? I read that as "given in Rome". I had imagined the participle would refer to *dies* in the Latin precursor to "date", but it doesn't have to be so.

Comment: I coudn't say, but I have always had that impression

Comment: Interesting searches: [datum Romae](https://www.google.com/search?q=datum+romae&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) and [data Romae](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=firefox-b&ei=fuYsXLXbNMiuwATlyq3oBw&q=data+romae&oq=data+romae&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11304.12004..12191...1.0..0.84.134.2......0....1..gws-wiz.N2W097zbBwQ) maybe I was wrong about _datae_, specifically. There is also a number of occurrences of [datis Romae](https://www.google.com/search?q=datis+romae)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reference, this is what the OED has to say:

> Etymology: < Anglo-Norman dat, Anglo-Norman and Middle French date
>   (Middle French datte ; French date ) regnal year (1230 or earlier),
>   date (specified on a document) (1281 in Old French), date (more
>   generally) (1314 or earlier) < post-classical Latin data (6th cent.;
>   frequently from 11th cent. in British sources), use as noun (see note)
>   of feminine singular of datus , past participle of dare to give (see
>   datum n.). In classical Latin, the date of a letter was expressed by a
>   phrase such as data xiiii K. Maias de Tarentino ‘(letter) sent from
>   Tarentum on 18th April’ (Cicero Letters to Atticus 3. 6. 1), litteras
>   datas a litoribus Britanniae proximis a. d. vi Kal. Octobr. ‘letter
>   sent from the nearest shores of Britain on 26th September’ (Cicero
>   Letters to Atticus 4. 18 . 5), litterarum datarum dies prid. Kal. Ian.
>   ‘the day of a letter sent on 31st December’ (Cicero Letters to Atticus
>   6. 1. 2). Hence data , the first word of the formula, came to be used as a term for the time and place stated therein. Compare Catalan data
>   (14th cent.), Spanish †data (mid 13th cent.), Portuguese data (13th
>   cent.), Italian data (a1556). Compare also (after similar dating
>   formulae in post-classical Latin using the neuter singular datum (13th
>   cent.)) Middle Low German dātum , dāte , Middle Dutch, Dutch datum ,
>   Middle High German dātum (German Datum , in early modern German also
>   date ).

Comment: Could _datum_ at the start of a letter mean "dictated"? I ask because I've seen _Da_ as a command from teacher to student to recite something, and I'm thinking that the Cicero class would typically dictate a letter to a slave/secretary rather than put pen to papyrus themselves.

Comment: @BenKovitz I would much like to see that as a separate question. Too interesting to be buried in comments here, I think.

Answer (score 3):

There seems no reason to doubt that the English 'date' and similar words in other languages derive from the perfect participle of *dare*.

A very plausible origin is as a a relic of *litterae datae* which was used to indicate the date on which a letter was handed over to a courier. This is also shown in the singular form *[epistola] data* quoted in the extract from the OED provided by @fdb.